# Response Headers Empty

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

I'm making a chatting app. I have the following problem: when I send a request to the server's response doesn't contain any headers. I want to check the token some header but that header is empty.

When I used to postman, I saw the token in header. However when I use fetch api in javascript, I see header but header inside is empty. Also I see header in google developer tools.

I think, It's dont about CORS.

```
static async userLogin(username,password){

    const url = `http://localhost:9090/api/authenticate?username=${username}&password=${password}`;

    await fetch(url,{
        method: "GET",
    }).then(response => console.log(response));

}
```

[image: developer tools]

[image: postman]

Comment: You are running into CORS. Your frontend app must be on a different domain than your backend API server. And in this case CORS only allows specific headers to be set. Check this link for better understanding - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Examples_of_access_control_scenarios

Comment: That's my cors configuration function. If it's wrong, I shouldn't see token in  developer tools

`CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);`

Comment: Ok. If you say you can see the headers in developer tools but not in code. Try using `res.headers.get('header_key')`

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else running into the same issue, use [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-expose-headers) which lets a server whitelist headers that Javascript (such as getResponseHeader()) in browsers are allowed to access.

Even after using this the `response.headers` was empty when I was using `fetch` and when I switched to `XMLHttpRequest` and used [getResponseHeaders()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader), it worked.